# Keyboard with 2 plugs not working properly in a laptop via a USB KVM switch

Tags: usb, laptop, keyboard, kvm-switch

[image]

I have a set-up like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pdjzo.png) where a keyboard and mouse are connected into a USB (KVM) switch, which then connects to both PC and laptop (via one cable) and I frequently flick between the two.

It all worked well until I recently upgraded to a modern gaming keyboard with 2 USB plugs. (Not exactly sure if the 2nd plug is for a passthrough port and/or provides extra power for LED lights.)

The problem is - the keyboard doesn't work, but only when the USB switch is pointing to a laptop. The keyboard intermittently powers on and off so it's practically impossible to use. It works fine when the USB switch is pointing to a PC. Also works fine if plugged directly into laptop's sockets w/o the switch.

I feel like it's almost there, maybe there is some setting to adjust? The OS is Windows 10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't gaming keyboards typically work with KVM switches?](https://superuser.com/questions/1558951/why-dont-gaming-keyboards-typically-work-with-kvm-switches)

Comment: @gronostaj not sure, looks like a slightly different issue. The OP there couldn't get a certain key combination to work but was otherwise fine. My setup is causing intermittent glitching a few times per minute.